# Automatic Sizing Of TableLayoutPanel

Tags: vb.net, winforms, tablelayoutpanel, flowlayoutpanel

I have a `TableLayoutPanel` within a `FlowLayoutPanel` so that I can have a 3D border around the table, but be able to define the positions of controls within the table as I wish. I would like to have the `TableLayoutPanel` fill the `FlowLayoutPanel` but when I use the docking property, the TLP seems to bunch up at the top of the FLP.

How can I get the TLP to dock so that it will resize when the form is resized?

Comment: Don't use a FlowLayoutPanel.  Just a Panel.

Comment: Or don't allow a form's size to change.

Comment: Unfortunately, some users are married to 800 x 600 resolution while others have saner settings, so resizing is something I am stuck with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally find that Docking is more trouble than it's worth.  In most cases Anchoring seems to work far better for me.  Try disabling docking, then resizing the control so that it fills the panel they way you want, then setting it to anchor on left, right, top, and bottom.

Also, as others have mentioned, try using a normal panel instead of a FlowLayoutPanel.  The specific layout panels have special code in them that handles resizing child elements that will probably interfere with your other resize logic.

***ADDENDUM***

Docking always snaps against the side of the container and forces the 2 sides on the other axis against the edges as well.  Anchoring allows you to set specific positions and then tie one side of a control to it's parent so that resizing the parent keeps that side of the control the same distance from the parent.  99% of the time, in my experience, anchoring does everything that docking does and more, with far less frustration.  I think that Splitterbars are the one of the few times that docking is required, but even then it can be emulated using a splitter panel.  Things like ToolStrips and menus are the best use case for docking that I can think of.

Comment: Using a just plain panel made everything snap into place. I am still a little foggy on the distinction between docking and anchoring - I am inclined to agree with you about using anchoring unless there is a reason not to. Do you know when there would be a reason not to?

Comment: Additional information about when to use docking vs anchoring added to answer because it was too long to fit in a comment.

Comment: Thanks for the addendum, kind of what I thought but makes it less confusing to hear you say it.